# Nodejs/Express/Typescript require the module.exports

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, import, require

I am trying to create a webservice using Express, which will be executable from the localhost as well as an AWS Lambda using Claudia.

I want to separate the app configuration and the **app.listen** function.

My **app.ts** file looks like this:

```js
import express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

class App {

  public app: express.Application = express();

  constructor() {
    dotenv.config();

    // parse application/json request body to JSON Objects
    this.app.use(express.json());

    // parse x-ww-form-urlencoded request body to JSON Objects
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    this.app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('API server is up and running');
    });
  }
}

module.exports = new App().app
```

Then, I am requiring the app in the **local.ts** file

```js
const app = require('./app');

app.listen(process.env.PORT,
    () => console.log(`Application is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
);
```

My **package.json** looks like this

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-express-lambda",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "run": "npx ts-node local.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.1",
    "claudia": "^5.12.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "ES6"
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

Finally, running the `npm run-script run` will return

> app.listen is not a function
>
> Application is running on port 3000

I tried `import app = require('./app')` and it didn't work either. I am a bit lost in all those exports and imports, anybody can help ?

Running the **app.listen** from **app.ts** works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help, but you may want to try this:

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv' // or just import 'dotenv/config'

class App {

  public app: express.Application = express();

  constructor() {
    dotenv.config();

    // parse application/json request body to JSON Objects
    this.app.use(express.json());

    // parse x-ww-form-urlencoded request body to JSON Objects
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    this.app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('API server is up and running');
    });
  }
}

const app = new App().app
export default app
```

and in second file

```
import app from './app'
```